# Trying to add profile2 fields to user/edit page

Tags: 7, users, forms

I am trying to show the profile2 fields in my user edit page, but I can't figure out how for the life of me. I read that they should autmomatically show up but it's not happening..

I have added the following in my template.php:

```
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){

        $hooks['user_profile_form']    = array(
        'render element'       => 'form',
        'template'             => 'user-profile-form',
        'path'                 => drupal_get_path('theme','mytheme').'/templates');

    return $hooks;
}


function mytheme_preprocess_user_profile_form(&$variables) {
    global $user;
    $variables['form'] = drupal_render($variables['form']['account']);
    //???
    $profile2 = mytheme_profile_form();
}


function mytheme_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    global $user;
    $mainprofile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'main');
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'basic_information');

    //Example field
    $form['profile_basic_information']['field_field_1']['und']['#id'] = 'school-district';
    $form['profile_basic_information']['field_field_1']['und']['#attributes']['data-placeholder'] = "Choose your Field1";
    $form['profile_basic_information']['field_field_1']['und']['#attributes']['class'] = "input-xlarge";
    $form['profile_basic_information']['field_field_1']['und']['#default_value'] = !empty($profile) && isset($profile->field_field_1['und']) ? $profile->field_field_1['und'][0]['value'] : '';

}

function mytheme_form_user_profile_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
    //TODO
}
```

I also have user-profile-form.tpl which right now consists just of `echo $form;`

But the fields I am adding to the form are not being added.. I'm not sure that the form_alter is affecting the output (it is running, though).

Comment: Profile2 fields for which users have edit permission should definitely show up without you having to write any code.  Try switching to a different theme temporarily to see if one of your templates is interfering.

Comment: it's a fully customized theme built from scratch so it may be missing some important variables etc.. do you know what variables should be in there?

Comment: No, I can't give you a list here.  You should check one of the popular base themes (Zen) as a reference.

Comment: i was looking at Bartik/core, and got head, styles, scripts, page-top, page-bottom.. still no dice. it does show up in Bartik tho hm. if i load edit/user/basic_information i just get a blank page in my theme so definitely missing something

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is an issue regarding with your theme. I have also built a theme from scratch but its showing perfectly up there. You need to change the display settings while you edit your profile type. SO under profile type edit you would find options such as Manage fields, Display fields etc. Under Display fields there would be three tabs just below them...Default, User Account, and Profile Page. By default, the fields which are not required are hidden, you need to change them and then they should show up[image]

Comment: This has the profile fields on separate tabs though. It appears the person posting the question wants the fields to display on the main user account edit tab, not in separate tabs.

Comment: I have the same question,how to make the profile fields  appear on the user edit page i.e. one page.How did you solve that?

Comment: When installing the panopoly distribution, it works! Profile fields are inside the regular user edit form. But what is the setup need to create that magic?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Account Profile](https://drupal.org/project/account_profile) module:

> Merges [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) forms into user account form.
>
> Profile2 by default creates an additional tab for each new profile
>   assigned to a user. Alternatively the submodule "Profile2 pages"
>   provides a separated pages for viewing and editing profiles.